# Expandable ListView with table

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, expandablelistview

The Expandable ListView should have following abilities

For the first steps I need to know how I create this Expandable View with this three abilities, small, med, big (with table)

Main:

```
public class En : AppCompatActivity
{

    public List<Ml> list;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        list = new List<Mdel>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            if (i % 5 == 0)
                list.Add(new Mdel
                {

                });
            else
            {
                list.Add(new Mdel
                {
                    Na = "N " + i,
                    Dels = "Dels " + i,
                    Ln = "Loon " + i,
                    Te = "Te " + i,
                    isDone = false
                });
            }
        }

        ListView lv = (ListView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.oi);
        oi.Adapter = new Myter(this, list);
        oi.Itck += Miew_ItemClick;

}
}
```

Comment: If you show what you tried, we can help you better

Comment: As it currently stands, it's a too broad question to answer. Take a look at `ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate` and `ListView.ItemTemplate`, that should help you. If you then encounter a specific problem, you should ask a new question.

Comment: [Example for expandable ListView](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/87282/hide-listview-groupheader)

Comment: Do the 3) (small row) row as your non-expanded row. If you expand it, you will get 2) (big row). Then you add another row under each small row. If it's not expanded and not marked as done, you set Visibility to true. Like this you get your med row in 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is, how to create this View with this 3 steps in it. Small row, med row and the bigger row with the table in it

I don't think a `ExpandableListView` is needed here, just from the description of this question, it's still a one-one relationship for each item, I think `ExpandableListView` is more suitable for the case which has root-children relationship between the items.

Here what you need is a custom adapter with custom adapter for the item view.

For example, create your data model first:

```cs
public class MyDataModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }

    public bool isDone { get; set; }
}
```

Create your custom adapter with item layout like this:

```cs
public class MyLVAdapter : BaseAdapter<MyDataModel>
{
    private List<MyDataModel> items = new List<MyDataModel>();
    private Activity context;

    public MyLVAdapter(Activity context, List<MyDataModel> items) : base()
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    public override MyDataModel this[int position]
    {
        get { return items[position]; }
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return items.Count; }
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView; // re-use an existing view, if one is available
        if (view == null)
        { // otherwise create a new one
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.mycell, null);
        }

        TextView nametv = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.name);
        TextView taltv = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.timeandlocation);
        GridLayout layout = view.FindViewById<GridLayout>(Resource.Id.details);
        TextView detailtime = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.detailtime);
        TextView detailtv = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.detailtv);

        nametv.Text = items[position].Name;
        taltv.Text = "Time: " + items[position].Time + "Location: " + items[position].Location;

        detailtime.Text = items[position].Time;
        detailtv.Text = items[position].Details;

        layout.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;

        if (items[position].isDone)
        {
            taltv.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

The item view is like this, you can replace it with your own one:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" />

  <TextView android:id="@+id/timeandlocation"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent" />

  <GridLayout android:id="@+id/details"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:rowCount="1"
              android:columnCount="2">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/detailtime"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/detailtv"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
  </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I made some fake data for testing in activity:

```cs
public List<MyDataModel> list;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    list = new List<MyDataModel>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        if (i % 5 == 0)
            list.Add(new MyDataModel
            {
                Name = "Name " + i,
                Details = "Details " + i,
                Location = "Location " + i,
                Time = "Time " + i,
                isDone = true
            });
        else
        {
            list.Add(new MyDataModel
            {
                Name = "Name " + i,
                Details = "Details " + i,
                Location = "Location " + i,
                Time = "Time " + i,
                isDone = false
            });
        }
    }

    ListView lv = (ListView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.lv);
    lv.Adapter = new MyLVAdapter(this, list);
    lv.ItemClick += MListView_ItemClick;
}
```

And in the item click event change the visibility of the view:

```cs
private void MListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var view1 = e.View.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.timeandlocation);
    var view2 = e.View.FindViewById<GridLayout>(Resource.Id.details);
    if (view2.Visibility == ViewStates.Gone)
    {
        view1.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        view2.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        if (!list[e.Position].isDone)
            view1.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        view2.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @My_yz, sorry for the late responding, this `lv` is a null by your side, it means that you didn't correctly find the `ListView` element from the view of your activity, maybe you can show your layout of your activity.

Comment: @My_yz, yes, there should be a `ListView` control with ID "lv".

Comment: @My_yz, still the same problem? Make sure your `EinsatzMain` has a `ListView` with id "lv".

Comment: @My_yz, it is done in the `ItemClick` event of `ListView` control, to make the view visible or gone.

Comment: @My_yz, are you asking what to do next? Change the `MyDataModel` to your data model and design the layout for each cell by yourself. If you find this answer helpful, could you please mark this answer?

Comment: @My_yz, and thank you. If you have other questions, please post a new thread.

Comment: @My_yz, yes, it's a normal `ListView`, NOT expandable listview control, usually Expandable listview is used for the scenario that many groups with different title and each has many children items.